# Java calendar method

Tags: java, android

Why does this keep returning 0?

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)?
```

Comment: By any chance is it between 12:00am and 12:59am in your time zone?

Comment: The value of HOUR_OF_DAY is from 0-24. Perhaps when you run that code, the equivalent time is 0. Did you try running it per hour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` will be 0 whenever the hour of the day falls between between midnight and one o'clock in the morning. So chances are, either it is in that time interval wherever you are, or your Android emulator is set up so it thinks you're in that time interval.

If that's not the case, you could try setting the hour to some arbitrary value and then getting it again to check that it's working. To do that, try:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally it should not,

Try this

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR));
System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

Nothing different from what you have except I am trying to print year,hour, hour of day,minute.

Comment: hrmm... maybe it's my android emulator? But this seems to work fine: calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);